# TFS 2010 source control backup/restore

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

Is there a way to backup just the source control component of a team project and restore it into a different TFS server?  We setup a TFS 2010 server for RND, but decided to use it's source control manager for a development project.  We did this so the developers can learn how to work with it before we use it on a much bigger project. Now, we need to blow away the server since it is a VM for RND. We're going to setup a new TFS server for production.  I don't want to lose the source code history.

Comment: Move Team Foundation Server from One Hardware Configuration to Another: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404869%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: Don't use move server - that moves the whole instance.  Move the collection (where your artifacts are) using dettach/attach.  That's why it was added to the product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the features built into the product.  In Dev10, collections were added so artifacts (including source) would be portable between TFS servers - leverage that.  Pilot projects were a key scenario for portable artifacts and a justification for collections.

Dettach the collection from the VM TFS instance.  It's available from the collection node of the admin console.

Backup the database from the database you dettached.

Deploy the new real server (non-VM).

Restore that collection database to the sql server used for the production instance.

Using the administration console collections node, attach the collection to the newly deployed TFS server.

Now you have the source available from the prototype period and you have a new production collection available for the new production instance.

BTW, in Dev 11 (you can get build conference CTP or beta soon) TFS upgrades the collection on attach so if you deploy a Dev11 TFS server, you can attach that prototype collection and pull it forward.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the TFS Integration Tools to migrate source with history for one or more Team Projects to another server.  It is very easy to use.

[TFS Integration Tools Download](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f854dd59-8eeb-4673-8d9a-ae012989bfa2)

I hope this helps

Mike

Comment: The integration tools were intended for migration and mirroring solutions -that's not warranted here.

Comment: This sounds like a valid migration scenario to me.  I agree you can also backup and restore the collection database but that seems like overkill.  I would prefer to start clean and only migrate what I want.

Comment: Dettach/Attach is a much lighter weight, full fidelity, better tested and designed into the product way of moving the resources.  The integration tools are much heaver weight, not full fidelity, more friction oriented way of moving resources.  Dettach/Attach simply copies some global configuration data and rebinds the database.

Comment: The scenario described above was one oif the primary use cases when adding dettach/attach ...

Comment: Thanks for the comments!  I think Detach/Attach is more applicable for our needs.  We actually thought about doing it this way, but we weren't sure if that will work.